# Require field validator is not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Following is my code and I don't know why my validator is not working
First code is User model then second is home controller and last is view of the Index action result.I am new to MVC.COuld you please help me.
Thanks

```
    public class User
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "UserName is required")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        public string Pasword { get; set; }
    }

     public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string uname,string pass)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
             User user = new User();
            user.UserName = uname;
            user.Pasword = pass;
            string Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"].ToString();
            string passwrd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString();
            if (user.UserName !=null && user.Pasword !=null)
             {
                 if(user.UserName==Username && user.Pasword==passwrd)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Home");
                }                            
             }  
           }
            return View("Index");
        }


<hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })               
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pasword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pasword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })              
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pasword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Make sure you have added unobtrusive.js and jquery validation.js to the page or layout both js after jquery min.js

Comment: What model do you use ? is it of type User ?  One more thing, you should better submit model rather then separate parameters

Comment: How do you expect it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you should send `model` instead of individual properties like

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(User user)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
               return View("Index",user);
            }

            // your code here if model is valid
            return View("Index");
        }
```

it will check if `ModelState` is `Invalid` it will redirect to the same view with `ModelState` which will include `key` and `value` so if validation of a property fails its name will be the `key` and message will be in the `value` of the `key` validation messages will be populated according to their `keys(property names)`